# Python plotting multiple colours to a single bar in bar chart

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a bar chart of features for something I am working on, meaning the data is anonymised. Essentially I am wanting to plot a bar chart, with some bars being a single colour and other bars being a bar divided into different colours depending on percentages.

For example, my input file looks like this:

```
+──────────+───────────────────────+
| Feature  | Percentage Abundance  |
+──────────+───────────────────────+
| Total A  | 94%                   |
| Small a  | 76%                   |
| Large A  | 18%                   |
| Total B  | 72%                   |
| Small b  | 14%                   |
| Large B  | 58%                   |
| Letters  | 46%                   |
+──────────+───────────────────────+
```

And I want a plot that looks something like this:

[image]

I've tried searching for any examples of this but can't find anything. I am using Python. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please be a bit more explicit about this:

"some bars being a single colour and other bars being a bar divided into different colours depending on percentages"

Also, there is no example showing.

Even without more info, I would still suggest starting with [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) and specifically [Plotly Bar Charts examples](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/).

Comment: Apologies, not sure why the image didn't attach. It is now there and hopefully it makes my lame description a bit easier to understand. I have examined plotly but I am still unsure how I am supposed to go about solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First create a Pandas Dataframe, then plot with plotly

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {'Category': ['A','A','B','B','Letter'],
        'Sub': ['S','L','S','L','X'],
        'Count': [76, 18, 14, 58, 46]}

fig = px.bar(dataframe, x="Category", y="Count", color="Sub", title="Some text")
fig.show()
```

[image: Barplot with categories]